# create a list of lists with a checkerboard pattern

Tags: python

I would like to change the values ​​of this list by alternating the 0 and 1 values ​​in a checkerboard pattern.

```
table =  

1       1       1       1       1
1       1       1       1       1
1       1       1       1       1
1       1       1       1       1
1       1       1       1       1
```

i tried:

```
for i in range(len(table)):
    for j in range(0, len(table[i]), 2): # ho definito uno step nella funzione range
            table[i][j] = 0
```

but for each list the count starts again and the result is:

```
       0       1       0       1       0
       0       1       0       1       0
       0       1       0       1       0
       0       1       0       1       0
       0       1       0       1       0
```

my question is how can I change the loop to form a checkerboard pattern.

I expect the result to be like:

```
       0       1       0       1       0
       1       0       1       0       1
       0       1       0       1       0
       1       0       1       0       1
       0       1       0       1       0
```

Comment: Why do you need a source "table"?

Comment: you can change your ```for j``` line to ```for j in range(i%2,len(table[i]),2):```

Comment: What would the result look like if table was 4x4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(table)):
    for j in range(len(table[i])):
        if (i+j)%2 == 0:
            table[i][j] = 0
```

output:

```
 [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: The content of "table" is irrelevant

Comment: how irrelevant? 4*4 or 5*5 are the same in this case. Or do you want me to update the output relevant to the question? I have made it for you.

Comment: @JayPeerachai from my point of view you have provided the best readable code.. nice

Comment: @JayPeerachai My point is that the values in the "table" list are irrelevant because you don't change/consider any of them. Only the size is relevant

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't appear to be any reliance on the original values in the list. Therefore it might be better to implement something that creates a list in the required format like this:

```
def checkboard(rows, columns):
    e = 0
    result = []
    for _ in range(rows):
        c = []
        for _ in range(columns):
            c.append(e)
            e ^= 1
        result.append(c)
    return result
    
print(checkboard(5, 5))
print(checkboard(2, 3))
print(checkboard(4, 4))
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
[[0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
```